# Tensorflow CTC Loss Sequence Length parameter

Tags: tensorflow

To which is the Sequence Length parameter of Tensorflow's ctc_loss referring to? Is it the lengths of the of the inputs or the lengths of the labels? Or is it referring to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's the length L of the sequence contained in the input tensor (which usually is the output of the RNN). 
This tensor has shape TxBxC.

There are two possibilities:

1. RNN output has fixed length, then L=T
2. RNN output has dynamic length, then L<=T, however, the tensor still has fixed size (each batch element TxC), therefore you have to tell the CTC op which part of the input must be ignored ("mask" RNN output)

Guessing that you are interested in the first possibility: pass a tensor of shape B which contains B entries of value T, e.g. for B=3 and T=10 pass [10, 10, 10].

Comment: Do you know what should be done with the label sequences which were padded with zeros ?

The sparse representation of the zero padded batch stores the shape of the dense tensor (dense_shape arg). Would the CTC labels include the extra zeros, adding noise in training ?

Comment: with the parameter sequence_length of ctc_loss you can mask out the padding for loss calculation. The dense tensor is padded, I'm not sure if the sparse tensor must be padded too, but I guess not: the loss is calculated using only the elements 0..sequence_length[batchIndex]-1 for the current batch element.

Comment: I'm interested in the second possibility. How would I pass dynamic sequence lengths?

Comment: pass it as the sequence_length parameter of ctc_loss for each batch element, e.g. [10,12, 9, ...] to specify that the first batch element has a length of 10, and so on ...

Comment: Can you please give the details for the parameters in Tf v2? The parameters are label_length, logit_length.